# C++ Block thread exit signal/function

Tags: multithreading, winapi, c++11, exit-code

I have problem with blocking exit function in thread.

```
DWORD WINAPI thread1Func( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{

    exit(0); // Problem is there

    while(true){
        printf("runnging");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int thread1 = 1;
    HANDLE thread1Handle = 0;

    thread1Handle = CreateThread( 0, 0, 
        thread1Func, &thread1, 0, NULL);  

    WaitForSingleObject(thread1Handle,0);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the thread which I have created in main function calls exit(0) function.

thread1Func doesn't call exit(0) statement directly. it is called by functions which has been called by thread1Func. So I cannot comment out or remove this statement.

I want to block exit signal from thread , What should I to do ?

How can I block exit signals from background threads ?

Comment: You can't, afaik. Would you mind telling us what kind of code is that? I mean, why can't you just change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, exiting the process ( at least on windows ) is not the good way, so naturally you should return an error code in your main function if you can like ERROR_SUCCESS ( 0 ).

So with that being said, exit is more like a forced exit compared to what you should normally do, I can only assume that it calls ExitProcess(0) under the hood, which as you may read it on the docs for ExitProcess it does what it says, immediately exits the process without snding signals or waiting for anything ( like pending operations ), so your best bet is to exploit the DLL loading and create a a fake kernel32.dll where you block the exitprocess or whatever exit() actually calls, or do the whole thing in memory like filling the call to exit with nop's so it does nothing.

I can only assume that you are using someone else's code so that why you can't comment it out, In this case you could try some debugging helper libraries that allow you to use debugger features such as break points, and simply skip the exit if it's not coming from the main thread.